# How to add new field to collection in MongoDB (NoSQL)

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to NoSQL database and using Mongo version 2.4.12. I have collection named as "user" and I wanted to add new field named as "useremail". Could you please let me know how can I do it from command line / shell terminal?

```
> db.user.find({username :"John"}).pretty();
{
        "_id" : "ajd233d-u980-4000-92b6-5353e9602502",
        "username" : "John",
        "password" : "John",
        "firstname" :"John",
        "lastname" : "Rogers",
        "enabled" : true,
        "employeeauth" : [
                {
                        "employeeId" : "a2fg190-b50d-14k2-aan0-ebb7298fa2b7",
                        "authorities" : [
                                "DEVELOPER", "TESTER", "CONSULTANT"
                        ]
                }
        ],
}
```

I wanted to add new field "useremail", so result show come like this:

```
> db.user.find({username :"John"}).pretty();
    {
            "_id" : "ajd233d-u980-4000-92b6-5353e9602502",
            "username" : "John",
            "password" : "John",
            "firstname" :"John",
            "lastname" : "Rogers",
            "useremail": "john.rogers@test.com",
            "enabled" : true,
            "employeeauth" : [
                    {
                            "employeeId" : "a2fg190-b50d-14k2-aan0-ebb7298fa2b7",
                            "authorities" : [
                                    "DEVELOPER", "TESTER", "CONSULTANT"
                            ]
                    }
            ],
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go `db.user.update({username:"John"},{$set:{"useremail":"john.rogers@test.com"}})`

`{username:"John"}` is the query and
`{"useremail":"john.rogers@test.com"}` is the update.

if the field `useremail` does not exist in the document, it will be inserted. if it already exist, the value will be replaced.

[reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Comment: Hi - It seems not working as expected, it overrides all my date and giving:
>db.user.update({username:"John"},{"useremail":"john.rogers@test.com"})

> db.user.find({username :"John"}).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54fcbae626f96d47769f86bb"),
        "useremail" : "john.rogers@test.com"
}

Comment: @user4567570 Please see edit. use `{$set:{"useremail":"john.rogers@test.com"}}` for the document update

Comment: yes, worked now. Thank you. It's a beauty of mongo. Just I need to get all my data back for previous wrong document update query.